# Can't see e-mails sent from me to my alias in google apps

Tags: google-apps-email, google-apps-for-work

I've set up an alias for automated e-mail delivery from a Linux box.

When an e-mail is sent from **me**@mydomain.com (using my Google Apps credentials) to **my_alias**@mydomain.com I can see it on my sent mail folder and not in inbox, where I expected it to be.

How can I change that so I'd be able to receive the automated e-mails?

Answer (score 1):

Does Gmail know that **my_alias** is an alias for **me**?

Generally when you send mail, Gmail doesn't clutter your inbox with it since presumably you've already seen it.

A mail filter might be able to work around this.

If that doesn't work, you could create a separate account for sending these emails.